# Converting a single array into multi array

Tags: php

I have an array which looks like this below:

```
Array ( [:status0] => 1 [:status1] => 2 )
```

I would want to convert it into something like this:

```
Array ( [:status0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) [:status1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 ) )
```

i want to do this with flexibility because the number of the array and names are random. I was thinking of using a for loop something like this:

```
foreach ($newParam as $row){
    $newArray[$row['Continent']][$row['Country']][] = $row['City'];
}
```

But i cant use this in my case, please help

Comment: Where do the `[1] => 1` values come from?

Comment: I also need to add that for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
$newParam = Array ( ':status0' => 1, ':status1' => 2 ) ;
foreach ($newParam as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key] = array($value, 1);
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [:status0] => Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
  )
  [:status1] => Array (
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1 
  )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vqEZs)